# Hiding variables in URL - the book

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I've got a problem with hiding variables in the URL. I read the chapter about routing in the Symfony book and it says: "Beautiful URLs are an absolute must for any serious web application. This means leaving behind ugly URLs like index.php?article_id=57 in favor of something like /read/intro-to-symfony."

I don't understand how I could pass some index to page without showing it.

In twig I have:

```
<a href="{{ path('AcmeBundle_some_page', {'variable':someID}) }}">
```

routing.yml:

```
AcmeBundle_some_page:
    path:  /some_page/{variable}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Page:some_page}
```

controller:

```
public function some_pageAction($variable, Request $request) {  
...
return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Pages:some_page.html.twig');
```

The result URL is:

```
app_dev.php/some_page/29
```

I tried also change the path and use GET:

routing.yml:

```
AcmeBundle_some_page:
     path:  /some_page
     defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Page:some_page}
```

controller:

```
public function some_pageAction(Request $request) { 
$variable = $_GET['variable'];
...
return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Pages:some_page.html.twig');
```

The result URL is:

```
app_dev.php/some_page?variable=29
```

which is exactly the "ugly URL" from the book :/

I still can't get:

```
app_dev.php/some_page/
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: You can't create a url with data that isn't in it, and expecting it to work, give the parameter a valid default value, and store it in a session

Comment: "someID" is changing, so I can't set only one value. It may be even several links on the page. I don't know if it possible to write linked value to session.

Comment: You don't have to: just set the session value to 1 (first page), and update it to 2 if the user clicks next or decrement its value if previous is clicked

Comment: Unfortunately "someID" may have various values from database (1,2 but 234,54,2343 as well) so incrementation and decrementation will not work. I must use some universal mechanism such as mentioned by repincln. It seems complicated for me but I'll try. Thx for response.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to show an id in URL like, app_dev.php/some_page/29. Instead of id you should use slug - https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md

Slug will convert your title (if title is for example My great article) into my-geat-article. So then your URL will be app_dev.php/some_page/my-great-article. You will then pass slug into controller, not ID

```
<a href="{{ path('AcmeBundle_some_page', {'variable':slug}) }}">
```

Take a look and read how to convert some property in Entity into slug. For example:

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=64)
     */
    private $title;


    /**
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title", "code"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;
}
```

It is very common to show slug in URL and not hiding everything. Slug is very good for search engines (SEO).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into it, it may take some time :)